# pandas dataframe interleaved reordering

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the not so good title and probably worse question.

I need to perform a super simple operation on a pandas dataframe but I'm apparently missing how it is called and hence cannot find the correct keywords to search.

Given a dataframe like

```
   a   b   c
0  0  46  14
1  0   7  14
2  0  46  19
3  0   7  19
4  1  46  14
5  1   7  14
6  1  46  19
7  1   7  19
```

I need to reorder rows to obtain

```
   a   b   c
0  0  46  14
4  1  46  14
1  0   7  14
5  1   7  14
2  0  46  19
6  1  46  19
3  0   7  19
7  1   7  19
```

Another simple and maybe less ambiguous example. I'd like to get from

```
   a
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
```

to

```
   a
0  0
2  1
4  2
1  0
3  1
5  2
```

**EDIT: some clarification about the complete picture**

For what it's worth, the dataframe in the first example is the cartesian product of the dictionary

```
'a': [0, 1], 'b': array([46,  7]), 'c': array([14, 19])}
```

i.e.

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 46, 'c': 14},
 {'a': 0, 'b': 7, 'c': 14},
 {'a': 0, 'b': 46, 'c': 19},
 {'a': 0, 'b': 7, 'c': 19},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 46, 'c': 14},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 14},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 46, 'c': 19},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 19}]
```

I needed to sort it so that for each combination of parameters all `a` values are grouped and cycled together.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['c', 'b', 'a'])`

Comment: Your cases are still degenerate; they both give the same output if you just sort on the nth occurrence of a value in the "a" column.  Could you give a more complex example (say where the second column is shuffled) and an explanation in words of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DSM I'll try, but I believe the the second example is not degenerate. Look at the index. For each value `a` can take I need to group all the first occurrences, then the seond ones, etc (a can take any number of values but each value has the same number of occurrences)

Comment: @ALollz only `a` column matters, see the second example

Comment: @filippo: it is.  `df.loc[df.groupby("a").cumcount().sort_values().index]` produces the same output, independent of columns b and c... but your last comment makes it seem like you only care about the a column?

Comment: @DSM yep, I added the second example because I noticed `b` and `c` could mislead you

Comment: @DSM I think your solution nails it. Would you make it an answer?

Comment: I see your point in the second example, where there is no other information, but in the first example the initial ordering of your DataFrame is based on sorting via ['a', 'b', 'c'], so the tiling by 'a' logic is consistent with reversing the sort order.

Comment: @ALollz changed data to be clearer and added some detail about my use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sort so that all the 0th times you see a value come first, and then the 1st times, and so on, you can groupby the column of interest and sort the cumulative count:

```
In [119]: df.loc[df.groupby("a").cumcount().sort_values(kind='mergesort').index]
Out[119]: 
   a
0  0
2  1
4  2
1  0
3  1
5  2
```

which works because

```
In [120]: df.groupby("a").cumcount()
Out[120]: 
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
dtype: int64

In [121]: df.groupby("a").cumcount().sort_values(kind='mergesort')
Out[121]: 
0    0
2    0
4    0
1    1
3    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Note that we're using `kind='mergesort'` to guarantee stability, and if necessary you can sort the original frame first if you want to turn `[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1]` -> `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]` -> `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the re-ordering all together by creating your `DataFrame` differently in the beginning. Instead of just using `itertools.product`, you can use a combination of `np.tile` and `np.repeat` to get what you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = [0, 1] 
b = np.array([46, 7])
c = np.array([14, 19])

d = list(zip(np.tile(a, len(b)*len(c)), 
             np.tile(np.repeat(b, len(a)), len(c)), 
             np.repeat(c, len(a)*len(b))))

pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
#   a   b   c
#0  0  46  14
#1  1  46  14
#2  0   7  14
#3  1   7  14
#4  0  46  19
#5  1  46  19
#6  0   7  19
#7  1   7  19
```

Comment: thanks, +1! I will definitely look into it, but I'm afraid the code that computes all the combinations which indeed uses `itertools.product` is a tad complicated and handles a good amount of quirks. As much as I'd like to move away from dictionaries and use something with predictable ordering sooner in the code path I'm afraid it will have to wait for now.